# How to resize background image on Safari?

Tags: html, css, image, safari, resize

[In Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVJlB.png)

In **Chrome**, it works just like the picture above.
[In Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSVJl.png)


**However**, in Safari, it does not work as shown above.

The CSS code is as follows:

```
background-image: url(rendyhome.png);
background-size: auto 66vh;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right;
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**background-size: contain;**
You can try with the following code that tell the browser keeping image inside the container, then, to center it. This solution may create a blank color around the image that can be filled using `background color`;

```
background-size: contain;
background-position: center;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

> A keyword that scales the image as large as possible and maintains
>   image aspect ratio (image doesn't get squished). Image is letterboxed
>   within the container. When the image and container have different
>   dimensions, the empty areas (either top/bottom of left/right) are
>   filled with the background-color.

**background-size: cover;**
You can also use `background-size: cover;` that will entirely fill the screen with your image.

**Be careful: using this technique, you need to know the image may be cut by the browser if the screen ratio is not the same as your image** (think responsive). As I can see on your image, there are some wording inside, so the cover solution may be inappropriate to keep them visible.

> When the image and container have different dimensions, the image is
>   clipped either left/right or top/bottom.

Both solutions are good, but effects are different. It depends on your behaviour preference. Even if image ratio is respected in both solution, one solution clip/cut and the other create a blank around the image.
This is an image from marcarea.com, in order to summarize. You can see behaviours I described before.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Look here:**
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

I would look at using

```
background-size: cover;
```

> Scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the
>   background area is completely covered by the background image. Some
>   parts of the background image may not be in view within the background
>   positioning area